# expand an R plot to accommodate labels on a cladogram

Tags: r, plot, label, ape-phylo

I've been messing with *pin*, *mar*, and *oma* with this plot but I can't figure out the magic combination that will accommodate the tip labels for the plot produced with the code below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(ape)

archosaurs <- read.tree(text = "(Crocodilians,(Pterosaurs, Dinosaurs));")

par(pin=c(6, 4), mar=c(0, 4, 1, 2))
plot(archosaurs, type = "cladogram", edge.width = 3, cex=1.5,
direction="upwards", adj = 0.25, srt=-45)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to adjust the limits of the x-axis for the plot, like this for example:

```
plot(archosaurs, type = "cladogram", edge.width = 3, cex=1.5,
direction="upwards", adj = 0.25, srt=-45,x.lim=c(.5,3.5))
```

Which will give you the following figure:
[image]